# PHP parallel rest API call

Tags: php, multithreading

So here's a simple problem. When a user performs an action, I need to send mails to all the users (and send notifications and do some other background stuff too) who are connected to this user (Using rest API email service vendor).

Now, while the mails are being sent, there's no good reason to halt the response of the logged in user.

Because PHP does not provide multi-threading by default, I am having hard time trying to figure out the right way to do it. From my internet searches, I found the following:

- PThreads: while they provide ability to do true multi-threading, PThreads are not supported in web server environment
- exec("mail.php"): invoking new PHP script in the OS environment seems like a hack which comes with it's own management issues. I am hoping a language as matured as PHP should not need a hack for this simple problem.

Is there any right way to do it? Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 0):

If its just about forking:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php

You could also fill a MQ (e.g. RabbitMQ) with all your stuff (Mails) and let another process consume on that MQ in a different (background) process.